# C program to calculate average and min of test scores

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program to find the average of students' test scores.  I'd also like to find the lowest score and drop it out when I calculate the average. I then want to display all 4 quiz scores for each student as well as the lowest score and the average.

This what I have wrote:

```
int findMin(int student, int scores[3][4]){
    int i;
    int min=scores[student][0];
    for(i=0 ;i<4;i++){
        if(scores[student][i]<=min)
        min= scores[student][i];
    }
    return min;
}
float getAverage(int student, int min, int scores[3][4])
{
    float tot=0.0;
    int i;
    float average;
    for(i=0 ;i<4;i++)
    {
        tot=tot+scores[student][i];
    }
    tot=tot-min;
    average=tot/3.0;
    return average;
}
void printTable(int scores[3][4], int min[3], float avg[3])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int scores[3][4];
    printf("Enter score for first sdudent:\n");
        int j=0;
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        scanf("%d",& scores[0][j]);
    }
    printf("Enter score for second sdudent:\n");
        j=0;
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        scanf("%d",& scores[1][j]);
    }
    printf("Enter score for third sdudent:\n");
        j=0;
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        scanf("%d",& scores[2][j]);
    }
    int min[3];
    float avg[3];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        min[i]=findMin(i, scores);
        avg[i]=getAverage(i, min[i],scores);
    }
    printTable(scores, min, avg);
    return 0;
}
```

It does not output the average and the main.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How's it going to output something if you never print anything in `printTable`?  Try compiling with this line if you don't know what I mean: `gcc my_file.c -Wall -Wextra -o my_file.out`

Comment: Your nested `for` loop in `printTable` is a noop.  It doesn't output because it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I thik you missed the printf in the printTable function